# Ros-phidgets manager segfault

Tags: ros, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just installed the ros-phidgets package and did a rosmake as it says in the readme however when I go to the next step to do "rosrun phidgets manager" I receive this error:

ERROR 1326402583.899881718/phidgets_manager: registerPublisher Failed to contact master at localhost:11311.  Retrying... master::execute

I think this is because I ran it locally and it looks for a remote phidget, but I am not sure. Why does this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12601/ros-phidgets-manager-segfault/) by [mcoates](https://answers.ros.org/users/1636/mcoates/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is happening because either your roscore isn't running, or your ROS_MASTER_URI isn't set properly.

If you don't understand why this is necessary, I suggest you read through the ROS beginner tutorials: http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2